# CasperJS/PhantomJS : waitForSelector('svg') -> svg sometimes doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs, casperjs

So here another trouble. I have a script loading svg and waiting for it to appear which randomly fails. Sometimes phantom stay stuck loading svg (even with a `waitTimeout` at 2min, so the problem isn't here I think). script : `http:// r.ccmbg.com/js.php?m=highchart=...`

I could still load the page X times in a loop waiting for svg to appear, but I'd prefer another solution. If you have an idea, I'm all ears.

Simple example :

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* Navigation on directories : ***********', 8,{
setUp: function(test) {
    //setLevel("normal");
},

tearDown: function(test) {
    //getJSON();
},

test: function(test){
    "use strict";
    casper.start()
    .thenOpen('http://www.linternaute.com/voyage/climat/paris/ville-75056/2013-2008')
    .waitForResource(/m=highcharts&/, function(){
        this.waitForSelector('svg',function(){
            this.test.assertExists("tspan");
        });
    })      
    .waitForUrl(/2008/, function(){
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "maximales");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "minimales");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "Paris");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "Le soleil");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "La pluie");
        this.test.assertExists("div.marB20");
        this.test.assertNotEquals(this.fetchText("div.marB20 > table > thead > tr > th"), " ", "Table first data not empty");
    })
    .run(function() {
        this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
        test.done();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: This also fails in Chrome, so nothing you can do. You found an error on the page, time to fix it. :) The error message in the console is `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/x-javascript: "http://r.ccmbg.com/js.php?m=highcharts&v=201310021033`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when I don't know the script called or the API used (so I can't debug myself), I just check the ressource now.

```
this.waitForResource(/js\.php\?m=highcharts&v/, function(){
    this.test.pass("ressource received (js -> API highcharts)");
});
```

Don't forget this event to get back page document error :

```
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});
```

[image]